# Ipad TableView for UISplittview

Tags: ipad, uitableview, uipickerview

I have a splittView and on the left side of my splittview I added an UITable.

```
@interface LeftViewController : UITableViewController
```

I also added all the functions which are requiered for the my Tableview.

I also can see and put data into my tableview...

Now I was trying to add a background Image or set the first cell as a default cell and I notice that I have nowhere a tableview declared in my code ( except of the tableview functions)

How is that possible and how can I set now a background image or select the first cell?

I know that this is the code to select the cell, but there is no myTableView....

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [myTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES  scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom];
}
```

Do I have to create a new tableview?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Customizations are normally done in the viewDidLoad method. Since you are using a UITableViewController you can access the table view through the tableView property.

```
[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom];
```